# How can I share a Queue between processes in Python?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I know there is a **[Value](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Value)** type could allocate shared memory, but seems it could only contains basic c types.

Is there anyway allow us to pass complex data types like Queue/Map between processes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Manager`s](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing-managers). Create a `Manager` object, then invoke `manager.Queue` (for example) to create a sharable `Queue` proxy. You can then pickle the returned proxy object and pass that between processes.

Comment: Thanks, @nneonneo, How about the Queue's performance if I read and write via multi processes ? Is it using Lock or CAS to make the shared Queue safe ?

Comment: The shared Queue is implemented using `Queue.Queue`, which internally uses locks to achieve thread safety. Process safety is ensured by the `Manager`, which controls access. You should benchmark the `Queue` against other approaches and to see how its performance fares on your specific platform.